# caught ExecuteBatchError exception on await call.write(msg)

Tags: python, grpc

Caught `ExecuteBatchError` exception on writing a message to the call of the following type
`call: grpc.experimental.aio.StreamStreamCall`.

```
ExecuteBatchError: Failed "execute_batch": (<grpc._cython.cygrpc.SendMessageOperation object at 0x7f3d1a7679b0>,)
  ...
    await call.write(msg)
  File "grpc/experimental/aio/_call.py", line 451, in write
    await self._write(request)
  File "grpc/experimental/aio/_call.py", line 429, in _write
    await self._cython_call.send_serialized_message(serialized_request)
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/aio/call.pyx.pxi", line 368, in send_serialized_message
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/aio/callback_common.pyx.pxi", line 145, in _send_message
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/aio/callback_common.pyx.pxi", line 98, in execute_batch
```

It seems [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/aio/callback_common.pyx.pxi#L145) is that place. Also, I see that [sometimes](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/aio/callback_common.pyx.pxi#L126) such exception type is handled. Should it be handled in `_send_message` too?
I'm not aware too much in Cython and what happens under these calls and would be grateful for any info or suggestions.

```
python 3.8.6
grpcio 1.31.0
```

Comment: Backlink to GitHub issue: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24758